# C# pass path in argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio, path, console, cmd

I'm starting cmd as a process in C# and I want to pass a file path in the argument. How to do it?

```
Process CommandStart = new Process();
CommandStart.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
CommandStart.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
CommandStart.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
CommandStart.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
CommandStart.StartInfo.Arguments = "(here i want to put a file path to a executable) -arg bla -anotherArg blabla < (and here I want to put another file path)";
CommandStart.Start();
CommandStart.WaitForExit();
CommandStart.Close();
```

EDIT:

```
        Process MySQLDump = new Process();
        MySQLDump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        MySQLDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        MySQLDump.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        MySQLDump.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        MySQLDump.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"\"" + MySQLDumpExecutablePath + "\" -u " + SQLActions.MySQLUser + " -p" + SQLActions.MySQLPassword + " -h " + SQLActions.MySQLServer + " --port=" + SQLActions.MySQLPort + " " + SQLActions.MySQLDatabase + " \" > " + SQLActions.MySQLDatabase + "_date_" + date + ".sql";
        MySQLDump.Start();
        MySQLDump.WaitForExit();
        MySQLDump.Close();
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Execute an executable file which takes arguments and returns data which can be stored in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the file path in double quotes and use a verbatim string literal (`@`) as SLaks mentioned.

```
CommandStart.StartInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\MyPath\file.exe"" -arg bla -anotherArg";
```

Example with an OpenFileDialog

```
using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
       string filePath = "\"" + ofd.FileName + "\"";

       //..set up process..

       CommandStart.StartInfo.Arguments = filePath + " -arg bla -anotherArg";
    }
 }
```

Update to comment

You can format your string using `String.Format`.

```
string finalPath = String.Format("\"{0}{1}_date_{2}.sql\"", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, SQLActions.MySQLDatabase, date);
```

Then pass `finalPath` into the arguments.

Comment: Use a verbatim string literal.

Comment: I'm trying to run mysqldump.exe, pass credentails parameters and then specify the export file. How can I add double slashes in the path automaticly, because through filebrowser user selects his mysqldump.exe and the url is not manipulated by the app.

Comment: @DavidWhite The escaping (double slash\verbtaim string literal) is just for when you're typing the path in the source. You don't need to do that at runtime, you simply have to add double quote before and after the file path (updated answer) so that if there's a space in the path, it's still considered as one argument.

Comment: @DavidWhite - I've updated the answer with an `OpenFileDialog` example. It prepends and appends a `"` around the chosen filename and then passes that to the arguments property.

Comment: I updated my question with new code. The problem is that when the process is started nothing happens it just freezes.

Comment: @DavidWhite Can you run the exact string via cmd directly (replacing the variables with harcoded values)? How do you know it's frozen?

Comment: Re-updated again. The problem was the escaping, now everything runs smoothly. Thank you! :) Just one last question: you probably know that you can specify the export file path and I want to do it, because now they are going to mysql bin folder. `" > " + SQLActions.MySQLDatabase + "_date_" + date + ".sql"` I get the app execution folder with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` but how to place it here ``" > HERE " + SQLActions.MySQLDatabase + "_date_" + date + ".sql"`` and concatenate all to become a falid path?

Comment: @DavidWhite If I understand correctly, you can use `String.Format` for ease. See the updated answer.